# Combine mysql table by two fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:

```
first_name  |   last_name   |   mobile  |   email
-------------------------------------------------------
a           |   b           |   123     |
c           |   d           |   456     |
a           |   b           |           | ab@gmail.com
c           |   d           |           | cd@gmail.com
```

I want to combine these tables and get report like:

```
first_name  |   last_name   |   mobile  |   email
-------------------------------------------------------
a           |   b           |   123     | ab@gmail.com
c           |   d           |   456     | cd@gmail.com
```

I tried to group by like this:

`SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY first_name AND last_name`

Comment: Unclear. What is your question ? Please edit question and explain chat happens with the code you give and what you would like instead.

Comment: You're saying you want to `Combine these tables` but you only have 1 table. Dont you mean `records`?

Answer (score 3):

When grouping comma-separate the columns. Also use `max()` to get the values of the non-grouped columns to avoid getting empty strings

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, 
       max(mobile) as mobile, max(email) as email
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Select t1.first_name ,t1.last_name,t1.mobile,t2.email from (select * from table where mobile != '') as t1 inner join (select * from table where email != '') as t2 on t1.first_name = t2.first_name;
```